# How to select non-distinct elements along with their indexes

Tags: c#, linq

```
 List<string> str = new List<string>() {
   "Alpha", "Beta", "Alpha", "Alpha", "Gamma", "Beta", "XYZ" };
```

**Expected output:**

```
 String | Indexes
 ----------------------------
 Alpha  | 0, 2, 3
 Beta   | 1, 5
```

`Gamma` and `XYZ` are distinct so, they are ignored.

I've done this by comparing the strings manually. Would it be possible to do it using **LINQ** in more easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach (var grp in
   str.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
      .ToLookup(pair => pair.s, pair => pair.i)
      .Where(pair => pair.Count() > 1))
{   
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", grp.Key, string.Join(", ", grp));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
var elements = str
    .Select((Elem, Idx) => new {Elem, Idx})
    .GroupBy(x => x.Elem)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

If you want to get a `Dictionary<string,List<int>>` having the duplicated string as key and the indexes as value, just add

```
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(e => e.Idx).ToList() );
```

after `Where()`

Answer (score 2):

You can get the non-distinct strings by grouping, then you can get the index for each non-distinct string and group them to create an array for each string:

```
var distinct = new HashSet<string>(
  str.GroupBy(s => s)
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
  .Select(g => g.Key)
);

var index =
  str.Select((s, i) => new {
    Str = s,
    Index = i
  })
  .Where(s => distinct.Contains(s.Str))
  .GroupBy(i => i.Str).Select(g => new {
    Str = g.Key,
    Index = g.Select(s => s.Index).ToArray()
  });

foreach (var i in index) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", i.Str, String.Join(", ", i.Index.Select(n => n.ToString())));
}
```

Output:

```
Alpha : 0, 2, 3
Beta : 1, 5
```